# If $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, does that imply $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}d(x_i,x_{i+1})< \infty ?$

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

If $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, does that imply  $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}d(x_i,x_{i+1})< \infty ?$

I feel like answer should be NO but I am unable to find such an exapmle. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Let $x_n$ be the partial sums of the [edit: alternating] harmonic series.

Comment: LeBtz : who would have thought that the harmonic series was a Cauchy sequence..

Comment: Eh i mean the alternating one. Sorry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**:
Take any conditionally convergent but not absolutely convergent series 
$\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ and define 
$$ x_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n.$$
$a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ does the job pretty fine.

Comment: THE canonical example (+1)